# After upgrade to 20.10 Thunderbird stops with parsing error

Tags: thunderbird, 20.10

When starting Thunderbird in Ubuntu 20.10 an error message is displayed

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xhtml
Line Number 905, Column 3:
  <key id="openLightningKey"
--^
```

and nothing more happens.
However Thunderbird can be started in "safe mode" with the command line command

```
thunderbird -safe-mode
```

I have a number of language packs installed, German, English (CA), English (GB), French and Swedish.

How can I make Thunderbird start OK from the apllications menu?

Comment: Did you install any dictionaries/language packs by any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem just earlier after installing an official language pack by Mozilla. After closing and restarting Thunderbird, I was shown a popup with the exact same message you posted, and couldn't get Thunderbird running again.

Based on messages in this (German language) forum thread: https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/thread/85658-thunderbird-startet-nicht-bzw-gibt-fehlermeldung-nur-im-safemode-m%C3%B6glich/?postID=468615, others are having the same problem, also after having recently installed or updated language packs.

I managed to solve the problem on my end by moving the offending file (`langpack-en-GB@thunderbird.mozilla.org.xpi`, in my case) out of Thunderbird's `extensions` directory. On my system, all my Thunderbird settings, including the exensions directory, reside at `/home/MYUSER/.thunderbird/RANDOMSTRING.default`.

Comment: This helped, thank you. In my case it was `langpack-nl@...`. After removing this file, I would expect the interface to be in English, but it still presents Dutch.

Comment: Nice catch, fixed it on my side using `mv langpack-fr@thunderbird.mozilla.org.xpi ../` in the following directory: `/home/user/.thunderbird/8rz2sdbv.default/extensions`

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287732/after-upgrade-to-20-10-thunderbird-stops-with-parsing-error/1287747#1287747) did not helped me but this did:

1. start thunderbird in the command line/shell/terminal with `thunderbird --safe-mode`
2. choose "disable all add-ons" and
3. click the button "Make changes and restart". Then it can be started as usual like using the the normal thunderbird start icons or `thunderbird` in the command line/shell/terminal.

Maybe this is a more elegant solution for users that do not want or can move files in the configuration directories.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around this issue on Ubuntu 20.10 by starting with `thunderbird --safe-mode` and removing all language packs (menu "Add-ons" -> "Languages"). Note that on my system I wasn't able to remove all of them since some of them were installed from Debian packages. Turns out the latter weren't causing any problems, though, and I was able to start Thunderbird without safe-mode.

In case you want to remove the language packs installed from Debian packages as well you can do so by running (adjust according to the languages installed on your machine):

```
$ apt purge thunderbird-locale-de thunderbird-locale-en
```

After doing so the list of language packs should be empty and you should be able to start Thunderbird normally.

Comment: This worked for me! (Ubuntu 20.10) Especially the first part: open thunderbird in safe mode and disable the language packages. Restart without safemode

Answer (score 0):

In particular in fedora 31 with TB 78.3.1 (64-bit),
I went to
**/home/MYUSER/.thunderbird/RANDOMSTRING.default/extensions**
and did following (which eliminated the problem).

```
% mkdir suspect
% mv langpack-en* suspect
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be a duplicate of my original solution.