# Thunderbird not starting with kernel 5.8.0-26

Tags: thunderbird, 20.10

I am on Ubuntu 20.10 having upgraded from 20.04
And have just done the latest updates this included Kernel 5.8.0-26-generic.
However, on re-starting the machine, Thunderbird won’t start anymore.
I get the following error message :

```
 XML Parsing Error: undefined entity Location:
 chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xhtml Line Number 905, Column 3: 
<key id="openLightningKey"
 --^
```

Any idea to fix it ?

addendum : I downloaded the tar.bz2 from Thunderbird site, and I succeed in opening my profile with ./thunderbird -P
Strange !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After upgrade to 20.10 Thunderbird stops with parsing error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287732/after-upgrade-to-20-10-thunderbird-stops-with-parsing-error)